# Can I update a Single Package with out a Full Distro Upgrade?

Tags: package-management, updates

I want vim 7.3 on my server.  I don't want to do a full distro upgrade just yet.  Is it possible to pull the next version of vim from an updated version of the repositories with out performing the full upgrade?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/vim

Answer (score 1):

You could get the package from the repository yourself and install it, but you need to be careful.

```
sudo dpkg -i <package.deb>
sudo apt-get -f install
```

What I would be concerned about is there may be reasons why the package maintainer didn't backport it.

Comment: It would be nice if package maintainers would make those reasons public, as it is, I am only left package less.  The way I solved this was simply changing over my sources.list file to include all the natty repositories, and then pulled it using Apt.  Seems to have worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install vim from a PPA. There's a list of vim-related PPAs [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=vim). A PPA is a small archive where users can put a handful of packages. You can subscribe to that PPA and track that the same as a full distro. It's the only good way to get new releases of packages on old distros.

Choose the most appropriate one for you (stable/bleeding edge/whatever), and follow the install instructions on its page.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest sources and compile it yourself (you will need `libncurses5-dev` and common build tools). This approach is more complicated than installing a .deb, but is more secure:

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
cd vim & ./configure --prefix=/opt/vim
make
sudo make install
```

In the end, add a symlink to new vim:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/vim/bin/vim /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Please note: you should remove vim package or give the symlonk a different name (`/usr/local/bin/vim73`, for example)